# Pagination, query more pages at once

Tags: pagination, query-posts, paged, infinite-scroll

I'm wondering if it is possible to do such thing on Wordpress, I have an infinite scroll to display my posts, I'm keeping track the pages updating the url:
 mypage.com/news/?pag=3

and I have a code like that:

```
if(isset($_GET['pag'])) {
 $paged = $_GET['pag'];
 } else {
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; };

 $args = array('paged' => $paged);
 query_posts($args);

 ....
```

if I get ?pag=3, I would like to render 1,2 as well on the site, so the 3 would be something like offset.

I hope it makes sense to someone..

Answer (score 1):

`offset` would skip posts, it sounds like you want the current page number * the number of posts per page-

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$posts_per_page = $paged * get_option('posts_per_page');
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page );
```

You'll need to keep in mind that total number of pages in the query object will change as you change the number of posts per page, so you'll need to keep track of that yourself.